# Warning message running Play - activator eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.5, typesafe-activator

I downloaded play framework from here:

https://www.playframework.com/download

And I chose the Offline Distribution download.

I set the path environment variable and added this:

C:\Framework\activator-dist-1.3.10\bin

While trying to create a new project I wrote in the cmd "activator new" and it worked.
Than I wrote activator eclipse but I got this errors:

```
C:\Users\***\Desktop\***\FirstPlayProject>activator eclipse
ACTIVATOR_HOME=C:\Framework\activator-dist-1.3.10
The system cannot find the file BIN_DIRECTORY\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\***\Desktop\·δ≡σ·\FirstPlayPro
ject\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/***/Desktop/%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/Fir
stPlayProject/project/}firstplayproject-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-persistence-experimental_2.10;2.3.11 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype#jackson-datatype-jsr310;2.5.4 ..
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cc8d2761242b072cedb0a04cb39435
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to FirstPlayProject (in build file:/C:/Users/***/De
sktop/%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/FirstPlayProject/)
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
[error] eclipse
[error]
```

Maybe it because of this error: `The system cannot find the file BIN_DIRECTORY\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.`

Comment: What should it be doing that it's not doing?

Comment: Aftre that I can import the project to eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `sbteclipse` for that to work. In your `project/plugins.sbt` file, add the following:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

Then compile your app first (`compile` in the activator shell). Then you can use the `eclipse` command in the activator shell.

More info: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE#Eclipse

Comment: Where should I find project/plugins.sbt file?

Comment: Inside your project folder. It is side by side with the `app`, `conf`, `logs` and `public` folders

Comment: Well now it works good. I got 2 questions:

1. Every project I should add this?: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")`

2. You know why I got this message after each activator command?: `The system cannot find the file BIN_DIRECTORY\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.`

Comment: 1) You only need that if you want to use the `eclipse` command. I have never used Ecipse with Play, but IntelliJ for example, can import the project without any command. 2) That is just a warning. That file is used to specify options to sbt in Windows. If you want to make the message go away just create an empty file with that name in the `conf` directory in the Activator folder (ie `activator-dist-1.3.10/conf`, not your project `conf` folder)